# Switch from openjdk-8-jre to openjdk-11-jre - trust anchor not found

Tags: upgrade, openjdk, ssl, 18.04

Today I tried to upgrade my server running a DAVmail gateway. On my previous installation I used openjdk-8-jre-headless without any problem. Now that I upgraded to 18.04 and installed openjdk-11-jre-headless I get the following error:

`davmail.exception.DavMailException: Exchange login exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty`

If I downgrade to openjdk-8-jre-headless again (and purge version 11) the error is gone.

I use "Let's encrypt" to create the necessary certificate - could that be a problem? E.g. that the new ISRG certificate is included, but the DST one is not present anymore? I checked /usr/share/ca-certificates and found both CA certificates but I don't know if the contents of the Java key store are the same and if this keystore is even used because I provide a PKCS12 file via `davmail.ssl.keystoreType=PKCS12` and `davmail.ssl.keystoreFile=/etc/davmail/certs.p12`. By the way, this package contains the `Let's Encrypt Authority X3` certificate as well as my own certificate and private key.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you use the passworfd "changeit" you should be able to list the certs in the bundle. For a `java` proc you can set `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit`. But I'd like to know how to allow an empty password like with jdk8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are affected for [BUG 1739631](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1739631)

The [workaround from the BUG](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1739631/comments/6) that worked for me was:

1. edit /etc/java-9-openjdk/security/java.security file. Find the line
   that says keystore.type = pkcs12 and change that to jks
2. remove /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts file: `rm /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`
3. run `update-ca-certificates -f`

Comment: We had to update the java.security file keystore.type from pkcs12 to jks and restart the java process for it to find the truststore file cacerts.jks
The issue with 'the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty' was resolved with this change.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands with sudo permissions

```
set -ex; \
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts -destkeystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts.jks -deststoretype JKS -srcstorepass changeit -deststorepass changeit -noprompt; \
mv /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts.jks /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts; \
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure;
```